# PHP PDF template library with PDF output?

Tags: php, pdf, odt

Is there any PHP PDF library that can **replace placeholder variables** in an existing PDF, ODT or DOCX document, and generate a PDF file as the end result, without screwing up the layout?

Requirements:

- Needs no 3rd party web service
- Ability to run on shared web hosting would be ideal (no binary installations / packages required)

Mind you, a library that is able to load an existing PDF file and insert text programmatically at a specific position is **not enough** for my use case.

As far as my research shows, there is no library that can do this:

- TCPDF can only generate documents from scratch
- FPDI can read existing PDF templates, but can only add contents programmatically (no template variable replacement)
- There are various DOCX/ODT template libraries out there but they don't output PDF

[PHPDOCx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) claims to be able to do exactly what I need - but they don't offer a trial version and I'm not going to buy a cat in a bag, especially not when there seems to be *no other product* on the web that does this. I find it hard to believe they can do this without problems - if you have successfully done this using the product, please drop a line here.

Am I overlooking something?

Is there a way to do this using PDF forms? I am creating the source documents in OpenOffice 3.

I may be able to use standard Linux commands (`pdftk` is available for example, trying that out right now.)

> **Update:** **Argh!** I was called out of the office and the bounty expired in the meantime. Starting a new bounty: As far as my testing shows, no solution works for me perfectly yet.
>
> **Update II:** I will be looking the pdftk approach soon, but I am also starting another bounty for one more round of collecting additional input. This question has now seen  1300 rep points in bounties, must be some kind of a record :)

Comment: Which size of placeholder variables are at stake? If it's just single words (or < 30 bytes) and not lengthy paragraphs, then placeholer preparation and a simple search and replace approach would do.

Comment: @mario they may be multi-line paragraphs but I could see to it that they are split into separate lines.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to parse out placeholders? What if there was just space in the PDF for the generated content. Probably wouldn't work if you don't know the length of the content though.

Comment: @Pekka, why can't you use a cheap VPS (www.lowendbox.com) and remove the limitation of not able to install packages/libraries? That would ease out the stuff. Is there a reason for shared hosting?

Comment: @shamittomar it's for a client, and I want to keep the technical and bookkeeping overhead as small as possible. A VPS would indeed make this easy but add a whole new parameter to the equation (A server needs administration, installation, continuous security updates, .... It can be down while the site needing the PDF services is still up...) that I want to avoid at all costs

Comment: Pekka, if the PDF is a big one and text replacement takes too long, won't the server kill your PHP script. You are better off offloading the job to a daemon running on the server.

Comment: @Pekka - Small note, FPDI can sit on top of TCPDF as well as FPDF IIRC, so via that TCPDF is capable of working with templates in the FPDI fashion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pekka,

I looked in to this previously, I think you can use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) (a command line utility), to fill in a PDF form using FDF/XFDF data files, which you could easily generate from within PHP.  That was the best option I've seen so far, though there may well be a native library.

**pdftk** is quite useful in general, worth having a look at.

**Update:** Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.fdf.php

Comment: I will check out whether I can get `pdftk` running on the shared webhost. It seems ideal

Comment: @Pekka It builds fairly well, I've had it running on a fair few hosting configurations.  The dependencies are pretty standard.

Comment: To complement this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389964/merge-fdf-data-into-a-pdf-file-using-php

Comment: @Pekka: Was this approach a non-starter then?

Comment: @Orbling sorry, I haven't got around to trying this out yet. Will provide feedback soon

Comment: @Pekka: NP, noticed the bounty added to it and thought that meant existing efforts had proved fruitless.

Comment: I use PDFTK for online certs and label printing, its quite handy but unfortunately many shared hosting providers wont install it (they'll try to get you to upgrade to your own dedicated server). However if you can find a host willing to use it, check out pdftk-php: https://github.com/andrewheiss/pdftk-php, it makes it very easy to take your data from a database and insert into a pdf form. For best results, create your form in LiveCycle (included with Acrobat Pro) as opposed to Acrobat

Comment: @Orbling it will take a few more days for me to work this out, but I'm marking this accepted because I have pdftk on the server. Cheers!

Comment: @Pekka: Glad it is of help.  PDF generation on-the-fly is a right pain.  I work in the print industry, *I understand*. ;-)

Answer (score 16):

This is not very practical, but for completeness: If you already have an ODT template, then you might very well retain that as template. Modifying the OpenDocument content.xml and replacing placeholders therein is pretty simple. If so, you could use [`unoconv`](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) or [`pyodconverter`](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html) to transform the ODT into a final PDF.

```
unoconv -f pdf -o final.pdf template.odt
```

Very obviously this requires a full OpenOffice setup (UNO and Writer) on the webserver. And obviously not every webhoster would go with that! haha. Even if it's simple on any Debian or Fedora setup. The execution speed would probably not be stellar either. But then it might be the cleanest approach, since OOo governs both formats way better than any PHP class ever could.

Comment: Yeah, this would be my favourite solution but I'm fairly sure the web host doesn't allow it. Still, for anybody who can use it, this is the cleanest way

Comment: Just need a VPS to do it. Hmmm nice solution. +1.

Comment: Besides, you need `exec()`, which is quite likely not available on a shared host.

Comment: @BramSchoenmakers: Depends. I have an extremely inexpensive and professional shared hoster. Uses suexec, fastcgi, suhosin instead of safe_mode etc. And they would most likely install Openoffice for me. But of course, it's a different story with mass hosters. | Also in this case you could use a socket connection to UNO.

Comment: Persuading the client to stick with odt and stack up a separate server for publishing pdf files could be nice too.

Comment: where can i find content.xml?

Comment: @shamittomar where could i find content.xml?

Comment: @Human love: Please avoid using commets for support/research requests. Google the [ODT format](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) to find out about the structure and XML meta/content entrails.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using something like XSL:Formatting Objects (XSL:FO)? Basically they're XML documents that are processed and turned into PDFs. Doing string - or better, DOM - replacements within that should be pretty simple. It supports embedding images, links, annotations, etc.

It's not PHP but there are a number of PHP wrappers for it along with ways of using it via exec, etc. Not an ideal but it takes care of the template portion completely. For some more info: http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/16/transforming-xml-with-php-and-xsl/

There's an implementation available as an Apache project - http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: Cheers @Casey this is very interesting, but the XML -> PDF portion (which, if I understand correctly, is what FOP could provide) is beyond the "no software install" limitation that I have for this project. Still, +1, a very clean approach

Comment: PDF output via FO works well enough for some uses cases, but since FOP's renderer is different to Word's, line and page breaks may fall in different places.  For this reason, a higher fidelity commercial alternative may be of interest: http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2015/02/high-fidelity-pdf-output/

Answer (score 3):

fpdf and there is another extention on top of it, which I can't remember, which allows you to import templates

Comment: [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) is what you are referring to I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to generate the entire document on the fly, with the template defined programatically using fpdf or something similar. That way, your text will not be cut off by paragraphs or anything like that, and you can easily position images/other elements as required.

Answer (score 2):

Late, but you can use OpenSource template designer https://github.com/applicius/dhek/releases , to define pkaceholders/areas over any existing PDF, then load it in PHP (as it's JSON format) and write accordingly on original PDF using fpdf lib, to generate custom PDF with dynamic data written on.

Answer (score 1):

Altough not exactly thing you asked, you may consider to make it at two steps: using some php templating sytem ([smarty](http://www.smarty.net), [dwoo](http://dwoo.org/)) to generate html page and then using tools like [Html2Pdf](http://www.tufat.com/docs/html2ps/) convert it to pdf. I am using it, and results are good (no problems with page layout etc)

Of course it depends of your input documents (can you use html instead of PDF/ ODT as source ) and complexity of the layout of those.

Comment: Cheers, this is a nice idea but won't work in my case, because I have office documents already containing the placeholders that need to be filled in (documents which the client must be able to modify autonomously).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm trying to help you solve the problem a little.

First the answer for couple of your question.

Q - Am I overlooking something?

A - No. There is a PHP PDF library that can replace placeholder variables in an existing PDF and generate a PDF file as the end result, without screwing up the layout

Q - Is there a way to do this using PDF forms?

A - Yes. absolutelly the tric to doing this is by using a PDF Forms

For both answer you can use Justin Koivisto fill pdf form field php library.
For more detail you please go to http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/tutorial.php.
Take a look there for additional information.

Credit to Justin Koivisto for his work

P.S

For workaround for displaying a table like output from pdf form
please consider to take some reading on [Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher User's Guide - Creating a PDF Template](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10091_01/doc/bip.1013/b40017/T421739T481159.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add this new answer since the FDF PHP extension is now dead.

I've just followed [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1426219) and ended up executing one perl script then the pdftk command

I'm pretty aware it's far from being a real PHP solution but it's reliable and fairly easy to implement on any *nix platform.

The tools described there are also available on Debian, just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

It's a litte bit late but have a look at the [PDFTemplate](https://github.com/Kommune3/PDFTemplate) Library it does exatly what you want. You can create Open Document files (odt) and add placeholders in it. The PDFTemplate library can fill out these placeholders (even with images) and create a PDF file.

[ODT Files with placeholders to PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJMvg.jpg)