# How to get text position in PDF using PHP, TCPDF & FPDI?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I have an issue:
I need to upload some PDF template with data and then change it.
For example, in PDF file is string:

> NAME:

I need get position of this string and insert some text (username etc.) after it.

Is it possible ?

**Update**

The PDF isn't encrypted. Text is embedded as text.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF isn't encrypted (no master/client password), and the text is embedded as text and not as a rendered image, you can just do some basic string search/replace on it - PDFs are essentially Postscript code, and you can treat that as plain text for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial and not possible with 100% reliability inside a PDF file because you may have to re-render the layout (to accommodate for elements moving, lines breaking etc.)

If you need to change some static form fields, you may be able to work with simple search+replace operations. For anything more complex, see e.g. this question of mine for some background and possible solutions:  [PHP PDF template library with PDF output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416667/php-pdf-template-library-with-pdf-output)