# How to edit pdf's and save them in the admin of a website

Tags: pdf, fpdf, mpdf

Ok, so I need to integrate a pdf editor to a cms site in such a way that if someone edits and saves the pdf it can be accessed via the admin of the site. Someone suggested mPDF but as I can see it converts HTML to pdf. 
In my case, the HTML form the user fills is already created,generated and saved to the back-end but there are some additional fields the admin needs to fill up and resave it there itself internally. How can that be done.
Can anyone please help me out with the same? Will be highly obliged.

Comment: I'm afraid requests for libraries and such aren't on topic on Stack Overflow. I can tell you from experience that this isn't trivial to do, though.

Comment: Where do I need to post to get an answer?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think a right-out "PDF editor" for the web browser exists at all, though. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416667/php-pdf-template-library-with-pdf-output) (asked many years ago when library requests were still on topic) might help: it's about filling text into specific locations inside a PDF. I never got it working, though, and ended up replacing the values in an OpenOffice document (which is easier)

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873/filling-pdf-forms-with-php)

Comment: Ok..thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.phpdocx.com/ was suggested but is it only for docs or does it support pdf's as well?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to regenerate PDF file with new data because PDF is not good for editing online and offline.

If you are looking to *add* text content to existing document then consider to use [FPDI](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI) open source extension for FPDF.